# POST Parameters arrives empty

Tags: php, ajax, apache

I have a very annoying bug since a lot of time and I can't understand it.

I have a ajax call to a php script and sometimes (a little percentage) the parameters doesn't arrive I don't know why.

In the script I check for the parameters if it doesn't exist then I send to myself an email with some information to try to find the problem.

I send me:
$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
and all the POST variables (doesn't arrive any of the POST variable, the list is empty).

Normally (not allways) the User Agent is:

"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)" But I don't accept IE6 in the web and I have a little alert to warn this and the analytics doesn't show any IE6 visit)

Is it possible that anything arrives to the server and this USER AGENT is a default Agent and not the real one?

Then, please tell me possible causes of don't arrive anything and ideas of information to add to the mail to try to understand what happens.

thank you.

Comment: Is there any kind of redirect happening that would lose the POST data. Could you switch to using GET and see if that resolves it?

Comment: Do you check the origin of the post? Perhaps it's a submission from another URL?

Comment: @edmondscommerce what kind of redirect?, I have some rewrites to get friendly URL's in the htaccess but I had this error before to add this rewrites. I need POST some vars could be long, but the most difficult part is this error only happens sometimes I can't reproduce never happens to me but I recieve this emails with errors every day.

Comment: @FDL how can I check the origin of the post? some $_SERVER var?

Comment: It's usually set in `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: I've edited the first message and I've added the web and a login user if you want to test.

Comment: If your POST request is served a Location header then any POST data will be lost as this can not span multiple HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause is a firewall or a proxy, you can try using firebug and Live HTTP headers to debug

Comment: This error only happens sometimes the problem is that I can't reproduce never happens to me but I recieve this emails with errors every day produced by some of my user.